# Fixed size list in Python not giving desired output

Tags: python

I am trying to declare a dynamic list in Python and doing various operations with it but after operations it is not giving desired output.

When I declare the list as general length like `arr =list()` it works fine:

```
arr = list()
arr.insert(0,5)
arr.insert(1,10)
arr.insert(0,6)
print(arr)
arr.remove(6)
arr.append(9)
arr.append(1)
arr.sort()
print(arr)
arr.pop()
arr.reverse()
print(arr)
```

This is giving me the expected result:

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

But when I am trying to pass a size to the list it is not giving the expected behavior:

```
arr = [10]
arr.insert(0,5)
arr.insert(1,10)
arr.insert(0,6)
print(arr)
arr.remove(6)
arr.append(9)
arr.append(1)
arr.sort()
print(arr)
arr.pop()
arr.reverse()
print(arr)
```

This is giving me:

```
[6, 5, 10, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10, 10]
[10, 9, 5, 1]
```

I am not getting why this is happening.

Comment: I suppose you mean "passing a size" to the list is  arr=[10] here, which is wrong. This merely initializes a list that consists of one element, namely 10. Also, what would you expect the output to be?

Comment: you are not passing a size 10, the 10 is one element of list `arr`.

Comment: @LukasR then what should i pass ??

Answer (score 0):

`arr = [10]` doesn't create a list that is ten elements long; it creates a list that contains 1 element, with the value of 10. If you want to create a list that is ten elements long, you could do something like `arr = [0 for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: `arr = [0]*10` will also do the work

Comment: @Izaak Weiss that is giving [6, 5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @Mandrek What are you expecting to get?

Comment: @VMRuiz i am expecting this

 [6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]